# how to divide one column into 2 column if data keep growing?

Tags: mysql

I want to ask about this

Example:

```
 1. 10078
 2. 10049
 3. 60232
 4. 10323
 5. 60032
 6. 60879
 7. 10378
 8. 60012
 9. 67321
```

I want to change it like this

```
 Column1     Column2
  10078       60232
  10078       60032
  10049       60879
  10323       67321
  10378       60012
```

Currenctly my query is like this:

```
Select [column_name] as Column1
from [table_name]
where [column_name] like '1%'
```

```
Select [column_name] as Column1
from [table_name]
where [column_name] like '6%'
```

The problem is I can not figure it how to divide 1 column into 2 column and keep the data connected.

*My friend tell me to use different views but I can not figure it out code

Comment: If you don't know how to connect col1 and col2, then how others can understand?

Comment: @Ullas err,  that why im stating that its my problem and I hope maybe you can tell me some of your view to make me understand
hmm

Answer (score 0):

I think below SQL useful to you.

```
select column1, column2, column1/column2 as div_value
(
Select [column_name] as Column1
from [table_name]
where [column_name] like '1%') as t1

join

(
Select [column_name] as Column2
from [table_name]
where [column_name] like '6%'
)as t2
```

Thank you.